# Customize BIM360 Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to customize the viewer used in BIM360, such as add more buttons and customized functions, so that my team can directly open models through BIM360's default viewer and use my functions. (I have these functions working on a separate viewer environment already)

I found tutorials about how to use 3LegOAuth to have my viewer access to a model in BIM360 Docs. However, I cannot find tutorials about directly modify BIM360's built-in viewer. Can anyone give me a sample if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't customize the BIM360 Viewer directly, that is not supported at the moment. The solution now is what you are doing right now, create your own App and read the model in your viewer from BIM360 Docs, then you can customize your viewer to achieve what you want as you already did now.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir!